# Stop,Step In,Step Over and Step Out in the KOMODO debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, komodo, step-into

I would like to understand what does it mean in the `KOMODO debugger` to
`Stop,Step In,Step Over and Step Out` as in the snippet below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the chapter [Debugging your programs](https://docs.activestate.com/komodo/12/manual/debugger.html) in the documentation.

- `Stop` : Means stop the debugging session.
- `Step In` : Means step into a sub routine (if the current statement is not a sub routine call, just step to the next line)
- `Step Over` : Do not step into a sub routine (if the current statement is a sub routine call). This means that if the current statement is a subroutine call, it will execute the call and then stop at the next line.
- `Step Out` : Means : finish execute the current sub routine and stop at the next statement in the caller